# Use Engine Routes inside of Rails.application.routes.draw Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, rails-engines, payola

I'm currently using a custom build of a gem that hasn't been updated to work with Rails 5.2 as of now. I've extracted the core files and now I'm faced with an issue where I need to access the routes for the engine internally. All folders for the gem, have the namespace **payola** - which allows me to access its resources. How can I setup my routes to take into account the namespaced routes for the gem, without including the reference to the engine itself (which is causing duplicates). My routes file is below. When I add the routes to the Rails.application.routes.draw alone, its unable to find the controllers for it.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'mobile_search/index'
  mount Payola::Engine => '/payola', as: :payola
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
  require 'sidekiq/web'
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  mount Resque::Server, :at => "/resque"
  mount CountryStateSelect::Rails::Engine, at: "/"

  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'signup'}, controllers: {registrations: 'users/registrations'}

  devise_scope :user do
    put 'user_change_plan', :to => 'users/registrations#user_change_plan'
    authenticated do
      root to: 'user_dashboard#index', as: 'authenticated_user_root'
    end
    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'home#index', as: 'unauthenticated_user_root'
    end
  end

  devise_scope :admin do
    authenticated do
      root to: 'admin_dashboard#admin', as: 'authenticated_admin_root'
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'home#index', as: 'unauthenticated_admin_root'
    end
  end

  resources :after_registration_wizard, only: [:show]

  root 'home#index'
end

# Payola

Payola::Engine.routes.draw do
  match '/buy/:product_class/:permalink'  => 'transactions#create',   via: :post, as: :buy
  match '/confirm/:guid'                  => 'transactions#show',     via: :get,  as: :confirm
  match '/status/:guid'                   => 'transactions#status',   via: :get,  as: :status

  match '/subscribe/:plan_class/:plan_id' => 'subscriptions#create',   via: :post,   as: :subscribe
  match '/confirm_subscription/:guid'     => 'subscriptions#show',     via: :get,    as: :confirm_subscription
  match '/subscription_status/:guid'      => 'subscriptions#status',   via: :get,    as: :subscription_status
  match '/cancel_subscription/:guid'      => 'subscriptions#destroy',  via: :delete, as: :cancel_subscription
  match '/change_plan/:guid'              => 'subscriptions#change_plan', via: :post, as: :change_subscription_plan
  match '/change_quantity/:guid'          => 'subscriptions#change_quantity', via: :post, as: :change_subscription_quantity
  match '/update_card/:guid'              => 'subscriptions#update_card', via: :post, as: :update_card

  match '/update_customer/:id'            => 'customers#update', via: :post, as: :update_customer

  match '/create_card/:customer_id'       => 'cards#create', via: :post, as: :create_card
  match '/destroy_card/:id/:customer_id'  => 'cards#destroy', via: :delete, as: :destroy_card

  mount StripeEvent::Engine => '/events'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a scoped module that would render the same results as the engine itself.

**routes.rb**

```
 scope :module => "payola" do
    match '/buy/:product_class/:permalink'  => 'transactions#create',   via: :post, as: :buy
    match '/confirm/:guid'                  => 'transactions#show',     via: :get,  as: :confirm
    match '/status/:guid'                   => 'transactions#status',   via: :get,  as: :status

    match '/subscribe/:plan_class/:plan_id' => 'subscriptions#create',   via: :post,   as: :subscribe
    match '/confirm_subscription/:guid'     => 'subscriptions#show',     via: :get,    as: :confirm_subscription
    match '/subscription_status/:guid'      => 'subscriptions#status',   via: :get,    as: :subscription_status
    match '/cancel_subscription/:guid'      => 'subscriptions#destroy',  via: :delete, as: :cancel_subscription
    match '/change_plan/:guid'              => 'subscriptions#change_plan', via: :post, as: :change_subscription_plan
    match '/change_quantity/:guid'          => 'subscriptions#change_quantity', via: :post, as: :change_subscription_quantity
    match '/update_card/:guid'              => 'subscriptions#update_card', via: :post, as: :update_card

    match '/update_customer/:id'            => 'customers#update', via: :post, as: :update_customer

    match '/create_card/:customer_id'       => 'cards#create', via: :post, as: :create_card
    match '/destroy_card/:id/:customer_id'  => 'cards#destroy', via: :delete, as: :destroy_card
    mount StripeEvent::Engine => '/events'
  end
```